# Inheritance or ownership between ndb entities in google Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, reference, app-engine-ndb, datastore

I am working on a simple online database for sharing technical equipment between artists.

I would like to let a class `User()` own entities of other classes such as a `Lamp()` or a `Speaker()`.

It seems that I could be using `ReferenceProperty` when using db, but when I look through the documentation for `ndb` it seems a bit confusing to me, as I can't find `ReferenceProperty`.

So If, using `ndb`, I want to let an entity of the class `Lamp()` be owned by an entity of the class `User()`, by referencing the id of a `User()`, what should I do? Wanting it to be something like what I have written below, although I am pretty confident that what I have written below does not in fact work:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.....

class Lamp(db.Model):
    owner = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
```

Comment: The replacement for `db.ReferenceProperty ` in ndb is `ndb.KeyProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `ndb.KeyProperty(kind="User")` as shown in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entity-property-reference

That way if you have a user `u` for example and want all the lamps owned by `u` you could get them this way:

`lamps = Lamp.query(Lamp.owner == u.key).fetch()`

And if you have a lamp `l` and want to get the owner of `l` you could get it this way:

`owner = l.owner.get()`

You could also use ancestors to reference your clases without specifying the `KeyProperty` as shown in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries